# Masking edges of S1 composite in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, sentinel-1

From the following code I would like to mask the edges of my sentinel 1 composites.

@Daniel provided the code.

```
var roi = Map.getBounds(true)
var startDate = ee.Date('2015-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2015-03-01')
var deltaDays = 16

var myCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi);

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var composites = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), deltaDays)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days')
      var end = start.advance(deltaDays, 'days')
      var masked = ee.Image([ee.Image(), ee.Image()]).rename(['VV', 'VH'])
      var composite = myCollection
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .median()
      var empty = composite.bandNames().size().eq(0)
      composite = masked.addBands(composite, null, true)
      return composite
        .addBands(
          composite.expression('c.VV - c.VH', {c: composite})
            .rename('VV-VH')
        )
        .select(['VV', 'VH', 'VV-VH'])
        .set('start', start.format('yyyy-MM-dd')) // Include dates of composite
        .set('end', end.format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
        .set('empty', empty)
        .clip(roi)
    })
  )
  .filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0) // Drop empty images
  .toList(1000)
```

I tried this but it did not bring me to any solutions:

```
exports.maskEdge = function(img) {
  var mask = img.select(0).unitScale(-25, 5).multiply(255).toByte().connectedComponents(ee.Kernel.rectangle(1,1), 100);
  return img.updateMask(mask.select(0)).set('system:time_start', img.get('system:time_start'));  
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the `angle` band to mask the sides of the scenes, only allowing angles between 31 and 45 degrees. There's often some noise at the beginning and end of each track, so I mask that out too. This might lead to gaps in your composites though, so you might want to skip that in some cases.

```
function maskBorder(image) {
  var totalSlices = ee.Number(image.get('totalSlices'))
  var sliceNumber = ee.Number(image.get('sliceNumber'))
  var middleSlice = ee.Image(sliceNumber.gt(1).and(sliceNumber.lt(totalSlices)))
  var mask = image.select(['VV', 'VH']).mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).floor()
  var pixelsToMask = mask.not()
    .fastDistanceTransform(128, 'pixels').sqrt()
  var metersToMask = pixelsToMask  
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().sqrt())    
    .rename('metersToMask')
  var notBorder = metersToMask.gte(500).and(pixelsToMask.gt(2))
  var angle = image.select('angle')
  return image
      .updateMask(
          angle.gt(31).and(angle.lt(45))
          .and(middleSlice.or(notBorder))
      )    
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/97698941ca6e15516ae890a0c2676e0c

Comment: Unrelated to this, but you might want to convert to gamma 0, to get a smother composite. https://code.earthengine.google.com/97698941ca6e15516ae890a0c2676e0c

Comment: thank you. But for some reason, I still have the edges in my roi:

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-69.98350047919075,-12.690380458271608],
          [-69.98350047919075,-12.643150122426537],
          [-70.05250835272591,-12.643150122426537],
          [-70.05250835272591,-12.690380458271608]]], null, false);
```

And yes, I know about the visualization smother. But I need these data for a f/nf classifiction so in linear values.

Comment: You have a gap between scenes, with no data at all. So masking edges won't do much to fix that? https://code.earthengine.google.com/593f27c6210183f2a3d5fb0cc900cc94

Comment: On gamma0: You can convert to gamma0 (treat Earth as an ellipsoid, not flat), then convert it linear for your classification.

Comment: To get more data, try switching between ascending/descending orbits, or increase your 'deltaDays'. Your ROI seems to have more data for descending orbits. https://code.earthengine.google.com/0e5a0b4ae62d9f7194331189c686c5d7

Comment: Yes, Thank you @Daniel. Always very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this same issue today, the solution above wasn't really satisfactory for our use case as it filters out too much data and is too imprecise. I came up with the following solution in python, hopefully it will be useful to someone else:

```
def maskBorder(img, buffer_area=5, pct_min_value=0.5, band='VV'):
    """
    Function that masks artifacts on the border of an Earth Engine Image if they are below a certain value. Can 
    also be used on a collection by doing: collection = collection.map(maskBorder)

    Args:
    img: Earth Engine Image
    buffer_area: How many pixels from the border should be considered part of the border.
    pct_min_value: Minimum percentile value below which to filter out outliers.
    band: Which band to use for checking if the value is an outlier.

    Returns:
    Returns the same image withdef maskBorder(img, buffer_area=5, pct_min_value=0.5, band='VV'):
"""
Function that masks artifacts on the border of an Earth Engine Image if they are below a certain value. Can 
also be used on a collection by doing: collection = collection.map(maskBorder)

Args:
    img: Earth Engine Image
    buffer_area: How many pixels from the border should be considered part of the border.
    pct_min_value: Minimum percentile value below which to filter out outliers.
    band: Which band to use for checking if the value is an outlier.

Returns:
    Returns the same image with border artifacts masked.
"""

# The minimum number of pixels around a certain pixel
min_pixel_count = (2*buffer_area+1)*(2*buffer_area+1)

# Mask for determining which pixels are on the border.
mask1 = img.reduceNeighborhood(reducer=ee.Reducer.count(), kernel=ee.Kernel.square(buffer_area)).select(f'{band}_count').lt(min_pixel_count)

# Minimum value of a VV pixel at the border (trying to filter out low outliers)
min_value = img.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.percentile([pct_min_value]),  geometry=img.geometry().bounds(), 
                             scale=img.select(band).projection().nominalScale(), bestEffort=True).get(band)

# Mask for masking values below the minimum value
mask2 = img.select(band).lt(ee.Number(min_value))

# Mask out pixels that are both on the border and below the minimum value
mask = mask2.And(mask1).Not()

# Update the image mask
img = img.updateMask(mask)
return img border artifacts masked.
    """
    
    # The minimum number of pixels around a certain pixel
    min_pixel_count = (2*buffer_area+1)*(2*buffer_area+1)
    
    # Mask for determining which pixels are on the border.
    mask1 = img.reduceNeighborhood(reducer=ee.Reducer.count(), kernel=ee.Kernel.square(buffer_area)).select(f'{band}_count').lt(min_pixel_count)
    
    # Minimum value of a VV pixel at the border (trying to filter out low outliers)
    min_value = img.reduceRegion(reducer=ee.Reducer.percentile([pct_min_value]),  geometry=img.geometry().bounds(), 
                             scale=img.select(band).projection().nominalScale(), bestEffort=True).get(band)
    
    # Mask for masking values below the minimum value
    mask2 = img.select(band).lt(ee.Number(min_value))
    
    # Mask out pixels that are both on the border and below the minimum value
    mask = mask2.And(mask1).Not()
    
    # Update the image mask
    img = img.updateMask(mask)
    return img
```